# Is cmp faster than diff -q?

Tags: performance, diff

In a recent Ask Ubuntu question on checking whether some files have differing content, I saw a comment stating that, if the differing sections didn't matter, `cmp` would be faster than `diff`. This [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12900693) concurs, giving the reason that `cmp` would stop at the first differing byte. However, GNU `diff` has the `-q` (or `--brief`) flag, which is supposed to make it `report only when files differ`. It would seem logical that GNU `diff` would also stop comparing once any difference is found (like `grep` would stop searching after the first match when `-l` or `-q` is specified).

Is `cmp` truly faster than `diff -q`, in the context of Linux systems, which are likely to have the GNU version?

Comment: @josten I would, but I am not sure how to go about generating test data (and if I did, I'd like to test it out on a nice range to see whether `cmp` is faster for some file sizes).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Prompted by @josten, I ran a comparison on the two. The code is on [GitHub](https://github.com/murukeshm/scratchpad/tree/master/diff-cmp).
In short:

[image: user-sys]

[image: real]

The User+Sys time taken by `cmp -s` seemed to be a tad more than that of `diff` in most cases. However, the Real time take was pretty much arbitrary - `cmp` ahead on some, `diff` ahead on some.

**Summary:**
Any difference in performance is pure coincidence. Use whatever you wish.

Answer (score 7):

Using similar, but larger files from [Anthon](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/153305/885) (100M lines, with a difference only on the last one):

```
yes | head -n 100000000 >aa
sed '$ s/d/e/' >ab
```

I get indistinguishable timings for `diff -q` and `cmp -s`:

```
/tmp% time diff -q aa ab
Files aa and ab differ
diff -q aa ab  0.04s user 0.33s system 99% cpu 0.370 total
/tmp% time cmp -s aa ab
cmp -s aa ab  0.04s user 0.36s system 99% cpu 0.403 total
```

`cmp` is slower than `cmp -s`. Presumably counting the line numbers is a significant burden.

```
/tmp% time cmp aa ab
aa ab differ: char 499999999, line 100000000
cmp aa ab  0.84s user 0.36s system 97% cpu 1.225 total
```

This is on Debian wheezy amd64, all running from RAM (on tmpfs).

`cmp -s` has the advantage of being supported by all POSIX platforms and by BusyBox.

Answer (score 3):

No, `diff -q` seems to be faster and you can easily test that:

```
$ wc x1 x2
 10000000  10000000  50000000 x1
 10000000  10000000  50000000 x2
 20000000  20000000 100000000 total
```

Two files with 10 million lines of 4 chars each.

```
$ cat x1 x2 > /dev/null
$ diff x1 x2
9999999c9999999
< abcd
---
> abce
```

Differing only in the one before last line.

```
$ time diff -q x1 x2
Files x1 and x2 differ

real    0m0.043s
user    0m0.012s
sys     0m0.031s

$ time cmp x1 x2
x1 x2 differ: byte 49999994, line 9999999

real    0m0.085s
user    0m0.048s
sys     0m0.036s
```

`diff -q` is almost twice as fast in real time, and stays faster that way when using repeated execution.

Comment: You should compare with `cmp -s`. On my machine (Debian wheezy x86_64), `cmp -s` and `diff -q` have indistinguishable timings, `cmp` is slower.